# ¿Cómo puedo recuperar lo datos como email, nombre y foto desde firebase y mostrarlos en una UIViewController?

Tags: firebase, swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var imagenPerfil: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var lblNombreUser: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var lblEmailUser: UILabel!
```

Esta es la función donde los recupero, al principio tengo declaradas mis conexiones de labels y uiimage

```
 func obtenerPerfil(){
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if let user = user {
        let photoURL = user.photoURL
        let name = user.displayName
        let email = user.email
    }

}
```

Comment: no recuperas desde firebase, lo estas recuperando del Auth que seguramente es google

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los datos de un usuario de Firebase primero has de crearlo con:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
    // ...
}
```

Si ya has creado el usuario, tienes que hacer login con:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
   // ...
}
```

En ambos casos, el objeto `user` contiene la misma información del usuario que el objeto `Auth.auth().currentUser` que usas en tu código.

No obstante, te invito a buscar en la documentación oficial de Firebase antes de poner una pregunta como esta ya que está bastante bien explicado.

Más info: [Autenticar usuarios con Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth?authuser=0)